# GPIO assigment?

Tags: gpio

Where ( header file name ? / config ?) ) do I assign I/O pin as "general I/O "?

I can see on Pi 3B schematic GPIOx and in parenthesis specific function , for example I2W.

I just need few outputs, but I like to keep them in specific area of the P8 as common bus between several pieces of hardware. 
I do not need dedicated functions as shown on schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (re-)assign any of the special functions, so they are given as outlined in the official schematics. As for the "general purpose" functionality of the GPIO-pins, well, that's for you to decide in software. Simply pick those that fit your needs, i.e. with respect to their location on the header (not the header file but the connector this time), and then stick with it.

Whether this configuration is done in header or config files is simply a matter of taste. If your coding a language with header files those configurations could be put there; if you need them user changeable (from your description it would seem that you'd rather not) you could also put them in separate config files.

I'll take [the Foundations schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-3B-V1.2-Schematics.pdf) as the authoritative source with respect to the function of the GPIO pins available at J8. These are 28 general purpose pins. Of those only two are reserved (ID_SD and ID_SC) which are used for the ID EEPROM scheme of HATs. So that leaves you with 26 GPIO pins, some carry a secondary function (alternate functions such as I2C) but if that is not used, one is free to use the pin.

> One of the alternate functions selectable on bank 0 of the Raspbery Pi GPIO is DPI. DPI (Display Parallel Interface) is a 24-bit parallel interface with 28 clock and synchronisation signals.pinout.xyz/pinout/dpi Please clarify . What exactly isn "bank 0 " ? AM I looking at wrong Raspberry document ?

See [here](https://pinout.xyz/) (or at the Raspberry Pi Foundation linked above) for the basic pinout. [DPI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/dpi/README.md) is an alternate configuration (which the original question makes not mention of) that uses ALL GPIO pins.

> Please confirm that Raspberry Pi 3B has ONLY 8 TRUE general purpose I/O ports Yes / No will be fine.

So the answer is: no, not in a general sense. Limitations apply only if one choses certain alternate modes (such as the DPI).

Comment: One of the alternate functions selectable on bank 0 of the Raspbery Pi GPIO is DPI. DPI (Display Parallel Interface) is a 24-bit parallel interface with 28 clock and synchronisation signals.https://pinout.xyz/pinout/dpi Please clarify . What exactly isn "bank 0 " ? AM I looking at wrong Raspberry document ?

Comment: Please confirm that Raspberry Pi 3B  has ONLY 8 TRUE general purpose I/O ports  Yes / No will be fine

Comment: http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples